# WCF SocketException connection refused, mismatched bindings

Tags: silverlight, wcf, socketexception

I'm trying to work on a Silverlight application that a colleague has wrote which uses WCF service for data, it works fine for him but I'm having issue on my PC. Upon loading the app it flashes up briefly before going blank, when a SocketException is thrown.

Opening the WCF service project with the .svc file as the default page gives me the WCF Test Client sometimes throws a FileNotFoundException regarding the XmlSerializers assembly but otherwise shows the methods it should. When I invoke any of the methods I get a SocketException saying "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" with an Native error code of 10061.

The service trace error shows an exception of "Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched." but I've no idea how to configure this or why it would be showing an issue only on my machine